# TYPO3 hide content element options in wizard

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

I want to show only the column options from the grid elements tab to the editors group when they create a new content element. So I tried to edit the groups TSconfig.

```
tx_gridelements.setup.tabs4 >
tx_gridelements.setup.tabs6 >
```

This has no effect. How do I remove all but the column options?[image]

**Update:** With your help I figured out that my problem is not about the text in the TSconfig but that it is **not loaded from the backend user group** nor the **beuser**.

Answer (score 2):

The elements you want to disable are located in Page TSconfig under `mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems`. You can see them in the "Info" module under "Page TSconfig" :

[image]

You can simply disable them by adding

```
# example for the given screenshot
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.header >
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the answer from @statix will work with grid elements.

But in the settings of your backend layout, you can define what type of content elements are allowed within a specific content area:

[image]

And within the settings of each grid element you can define again, which content elements are available, e.g. to prevent nesting of grid elements.

Answer (score 1):

As I was looking for a solution to remove content elements from the Content Element Wizard I found this video https://youtu.be/MG1IdpJVQzE and it worked for me.

In your **page.tsconfig** file you can either remove the unwanted items with:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems = bullets, table, uploads, textpic, textmedia
```

or show only the wanted elements using:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.keepItems = image, text, header
```

(If you cannot see the names of the elements – watch the video).

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in root page tscPage TSConfig

```
tx_gridelements.excludeLayoutIds=your grid id
```

May It helps you!!